# asp.net mvc 5 - system doesn't find a view that exists

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

So here's the code that's running:

```
return RedirectToAction("BadFileError", "Error");
```

Which then redirects the viewer to:

```
https://localhost:44340/Error/BadFileError
```

Which exists in 
[image]

What on earth am I missing here? Why can't Asp.net seem to see views that I create without using the scaffolding system?
Here's the error it throws:
[image]

Comment: Do not redirect users to show error messages as this breaks the nature of HTTP and REST. You should return error responses directly instead with appropriate status codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your browser will make a request to `yourSite/Error/BadFileError` and aspnet mvc framework **will not directly serve the razor file**.

You need to have an action method with that name in your `ErrorController`. The request will be directed to the action method, not to the view file. Your action method can return that view (or any other view)

Add this to the ErrorController.

```
public ActionResult BadFileError()
{
   return View();
}
```

Also, If you simply want to show the error view content to the user, you can do that with the `View()` method call with the full path to your error view. You do not necessarily need to do a redirect(which will issue a new http request).

So instead of the redirect, you can do

```
return View("~/Views/Error/BadFileError.cshtml");
```

Comment: Still getting my Asp.net legs over here.

Comment: Just an interesting side note. When you call View() with no arguments, it uses RouteData.Values["action"] to get the action name and uses that to find the view.